# Why are row columns overflowing down on larger screens?

Tags: django, python-3.x, bootstrap-4

My first row behaves exactly as I want it to on small and larger screen. However, my second row works on smaller screens, but the columns are stacking on top of each other on the right side on larger screens even though there seems to be plenty of room. I want four columns to line together.

I have tried playing with the left and right margins and padding, but it has not helped.

I noticed that in Developer Tools the computed page added an extra row to the next column item in the second row. I tried removing the second row as seen in the code I included. Although the only one run gets computed, those lower columns still stack up on each other on the right side instead of lining up.

Looking at another explanation, I wondered if it was a column height issue, as I noticed that the problem columns are not exactly the same height. I tried this:

```
.row.display-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row.display-flex > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

and this:

```
 .col-sm-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
```

But that didn't change the height or the alignment problem.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 order-fisrt col-md-6">
      <div class="vl">
      <a href="{% url 'detail' article.id %}">
      <div class="text-center">
        <img src="{{ article.pic.url }}" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <h1 class="title">{{ article.headline }}</h1></a>
        <p>{{ article.pub_date|date:"F j, Y" }}</p>
        <p class="article">{{ article.content|truncatewords:"35" }}</p>
        </div>
        <hr class="firstline" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    {% elif article.rank == 2 %}
    <div class="col-sm-3 order-md-first">
      <a href="{% url 'detail' article.id %}">
      <div class="text-center">
        <img src="{{ article.pic.url }}" class="img-second">
      </div>
      <h2 class="title-two">{{ article.headline }}</h2></a>
        <p>{{ article.pub_date|date:"F j, Y" }}</p>
        <p class="article">{{ article.content|truncatewords:"20" }}</p>
        <hr />
        </div>
        </div>
        {% else %}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <a href="{% url 'detail' article.id %}">
          <div class="text-center">
            <img src="{{ article.pic.url }}" class="img-second">
          </div>
          <h2 class="title-two">{{ article.headline }}</h2></a>
            <p>{{ article.pub_date|date:"F j, Y" }}</p>
            <p class="article">{{ article.content|truncatewords:"20" }}</p>
            <hr />
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: you have a spelling error in your second line of code "order-fisrt" should it not be order-first?

Comment: Thanks for catching that. The problem still remains, though.

Comment: are you also missing a </div> on line 26 or is it me not reading your code right? you have an odd number of divs in your first row 13

Comment: I searched for div and came up with an even number. And the opening and closing divs seem to match up.